# Rotated adverts?

Tags: support, advertising

A few days ago I encountered this 90 degree rotated ad on Science Fiction & Fantasy.

As before I'm using an iPhone and this was on Chrome on the full site with responsiveness disabled. That doesn't seem to be the issue though because normally adverts aren't rotated. I haven't reproduced it on desktop because I sensibly use an adblocker there.

Are these types of ads allowed?

[image: Ad on the page]

Comment: Could also be a bug, seeing that the image got compressed to fit the box, or an advertisers trick to grab your attention. If the latter, it worked better than expected.

Comment: @Luuklag True, the ad frame isn't rotated (buttons still in the corner) so might be a bug causing the image inside to rotate aye.

Comment: **Are these types of ads allowed?** If they allow animated ads and/or sexual content on ads, I don't think this is not allowed. although I have no official statement to put here, because there isn't one(AFAIK)

Comment: @Vishwa Unless I've missed something they aren't actually allowing sexual content ads, they're just not actively removing them/filtering beforehand like with every other ad. They're just relying solely on user reports.

Comment: "Shopify - you can use it by lying on your side!" or perhaps "Turn to the right answer: Shopify".